# Tracking information about time tracked to Salesforce

Tags: rest-api, integration

We have a product that allows our customers to do a basic integration with Salesforce. This integration allows them to track time in our software against Tasks and Opportunities in their Salesforce account.

We have a potential customer who is asking if we can record back the time tracked to Salesforce so that they can run reports on time worked on an opportunity or time worked for a user.

However, from my looking through the data model it does not appear that Salesforce supports any model to store time tracked against a Task or Opportunity. So am I correct that is no built-in functionality at all in Salesforce to do what the potential customer is asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of the box functionality available for this. But you can enable field. Also you can't enable Field History Tracking on Tasks or Events. You can vote the [Idea History Tracking for Tasks](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BpqcAAC).

So the only option you have for now is to build the custom functionality and based on task status populate end date field. Then your users can make report on them.